# Have a 1 Gbit connection but I not all devices are getting 1 Gbit speed from my ISP

Tags: networking

I have 3 laptops and a 1 Gbit network connection to my ISP. But when I connect my ISPs cable to the laptops ethtool link/speedtest precisely says:

- Lenovo G500 with USB 3.0 Ethernet and OpenBSD 6.2 - 100mbit
- Lenovo T400 with motherboard Ethernet Ubuntu 14.04 - 100mbit
- Lenovo T560 with motherboard Ethernet Windows 10 - 1 Gbit

All the HWs support 1 Gbit connection.

**The big question**: Why cannot the Lenovo G500 and Lenovo T400 auto-negotiate to 1 Gbit? 
It is a 1 Gbit connection to my ISP, but I can only auto-negotiate with 1 Gbit with the Windows 10/T560 laptop.

Maybe I need cross-cable? The ISP I think has a switch at the other end.

This is the cable that I have from my ISP:

[image]

UPDATE: I dd'ed an install63.fs to a flashdrive: sd2c, but only could boot the T400 with it (other Lenovo T61 and T560 just couldn't boot from it, strange). But the T400 booted the install63.fs, but.. it didn't recognized the cdce USB Gbit ethernet when I exited the Installer to Shell and plugged it in. any advice why didn't the .fs image didn't booted on the T560 and a T61? And how can I liveCD test with OpenBSD?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that cable is mashed, you should replace it. A cat5e ethernet cable will do.

The likely reason is that the other two laptops only have 100Mbit network cards in them, or only 100Mbit support in the kernel for the card.

Comment: IMHO this is a valid thing to try. That cable can't be in spec - blue-white is visibly nicked, it does not look (from this angle) that all pairs have been pushed to the end of the connector, too much exposed wiring. If replacing the cable does not fix the problem, are you able to force link speed to 1 gigabit? [it's probable different devices are behaving differently due to different chipset. Theoretically a crossover cable should make no difference on a gigabit connection)